# How do I run SPARQL-select to Wikidata from Protege?

Tags: sparql, protege, wikidata

I have a query that returns if page with such name exists in Wikidata.

```
SELECT ?boolean
WHERE{
BIND(EXISTS{?item ?label "Water"} AS ?boolean)
  }
```

Now I need to run it from Protege tab SPARQL-query. What do I have to add to it to make it work? Maybe some prefixes? When I run it as it is now I always get false :(

Comment: `?label` is a variable, why do you think this represents the title or name of the Wikidata entity of Water then? One more time, you have to start with a SPARQL tutorial for sure.

Comment: regarding your question, it does **not** work from Protege. I mean, obviously not, or did you ever specify the URL of the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint in Protege. For sure not. How should Protege know where do look for the data? That's not possible, the data could be hosted anywhere. I think you have to use some other SPARQL tool in your case which allows for querying SPARQL endpoints via HTTP.